# What is the meaning of “a polynomial amount/number of operations” in these contexts?

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, terminology, computational-complexity

I am currently reading the book ''The Outer Limits of Reason'' and encountered a description about which I am very confused. I am afraid to say, this may be due to the fact that I am not a native English speaker. these are the contexts from ''[The Outer Limits of Reason](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17841838-the-outer-limits-of-reason)'':

On pp.136, it says:

> Now that we’ve seen a few examples, let’s come up with a nice definition. We will denote by NP the class of all decision problems that require 2n, n!, or fewer operations to solve.6 A problem in NP will be called an “NP problem.” Since P is the class of problems that can be solved **in a polynomial amount of operations**, and polynomials grow more slowly than exponential or factorial functions, we have that P is a subset of NP. What this means is that every “easy” problem is an element of the class of all “hard and easy” problems.

and on pp.142:

> We don’t want the transformer to arbitrarily change an instance of Problem A into an instance of Problem B. We require that the instances have the same answer. In other words, we will insist that the transformer take inputs with a “Yes” answer for Problem A to inputs that answer “Yes” for Problem B. If an input to Problem A gets a “No” answer from the Problem A decider, the transformer should output an instance that will have a “No” answer. We make one further requirement: this transformer should perform its task **in a polynomial amount of operations**. The need for this stipulation will quickly become apparent.

on pp.169:

> Once we have shown that a particular problem is unsolvable, it is not hard to show that another problem is as well. The method used is reducing one problem to another, or a reduction.5 Suppose there are two decision problems: Problem A and Problem B. Furthermore, assume that there is a method of transforming an instance of Problem A into an instance of Problem B such that an instance of Problem A that has a Yes answer will go to an instance of Problem B with the same answer, and similarly for No answers. (We do not impose the requirement as we did in the last chapter that the transformation be performed **in a polynomial number of operations**. Here we have no interest in how long such a transformation takes, just whether it can be done.) We might envision this transformation as in figure 6.6.

on pp.179:

> First some definitions. P was defined as the set of problems that can be solved by a regular computer **in a polynomial number of operations**. Let us generalize. Consider any oracle X. Define PX to be the set of X-oracle problems that can be solved in a polynomial number of operations. NP was defined as the set of all problems that can be solved by a regular computer **in at most an exponential or factorial number of operations**. Let NPX denote the set of X oracle problems that can be solved in at most exponential or factorial number of operations.

These are repeated several other times but I think it is sufficient. My problem is with bolded parts. What does it mean "in a polynomial amount/number of operations"? because I always thought it is "in a amount/number of polynomial operations. Please keep it simple.

Comment: That book is *completely wrong* in how it defines NP ("*We will denote by NP the class of all decision problems that require 2^n, n!, or fewer operations to solve.*"). If you want to learn about complexity theory, this is not a good book to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the number of operations required can be described by a polynomial.  For example, to look at every element of a $1\times r$ vector requires $r$ operations (look at each element in turn).  This is polynomial in $r: P(r)=r$ is a polynomial and will tell you exactly how many operations are needed for any $1\times r$ vector.

An $m\times r$ matrix with $m\lt r$ would require *no more than* $P(r)=r^2$ operations to look at each element, so this is also polynomial.

Things change when you need an *exponential* number of operations to evaluate something.  To enumerate the power set of a given set $X$ you need $2^{|X|}$ operations, where $|X|=\mathop{\mathrm {card}} X$ is the cardinality of the set and this is strictly larger than any polynomial operation.

Things that can be done in polynomial time can be viewed as being computationally feasible (although some of them may, at the moment, still be larger than we have reasonable computing power to achieve).  Things in non-polynomial times may only be computationally feasible if we have a way to do it that isn't brute force.

Comment: Thank you very much. that was really helpful. so the "in a polynomial amount/number of operations" is correct and "in a amount/number of polynomial operations" is not, right? because this is the part that makes me confused more than anything else. sorry if my question is stupid because I think my inadequacy of the English language is causing this confusion.

Comment: Polynomial amount/number means that the number of operations is given by a polynomial expression (you will need to do a calculation to get the number of operations).  Polynomial operations are operation *on* polynomials or *by* polynomials on something else (e.g. you might be applying a polynomial to a set of ring elements to obtain a coset).  Your English, by the way, is very good and certainly not inadequate.  This is fairly technical writing so it's not surprising that it might cause you some (small) difficulties!